# Asset Pipeline issue in Production: Images not displaying with CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I’m in the process of upgrading Rails in a project from 3.0 to 3.2, and I’ve run into an issue where the images are not rendered by the asset pipeline in Rails 3.2 (with Apache 2.0.65). Assets are deployed using a CDN.

Only images are affected. Other assets (JS, CSS) render fine.

I’d like to know what I’m doing wrong here. (more details below)
Any pointers would be of great help :)

---

The images return a 304 Not Modified in production (both the fingerprinted version and the regular one).

---

**production.rb**

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
# I’d set this to true temporarily, but it doesn’t fix things

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

# Use cdn asset host
config.action_controller.asset_host = “<CDN-hostname>"
```

Comment: maybe assets' path isn't being set properly for images, if you're seeing broken images.

Comment: How do you upload assets to CDN? Your code doesn't explain that.

Comment: @PlagueHammer: Did you get any solution for this? IF yes, please help me out I am also facing issue with images in emails.